# For loop to sum each column of a matrix in R

Tags: r, for-loop

For the following matrix:

```
my_matrix<-matrix(seq(from=1,to=100,by=2))
```

If I wanted the sum of each column calculated I would just put the command as follows: `colSums(my_matrix)`

However, I need to create equivalence to `colSums(my_matrix)` without using the `colSums` function and instead use for loop.

Some please help!!!

Comment: `apply(my_matrix, 2, sum)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you explicitly want to use `for` loop here is one way :

```
mat <- matrix(1:50, byrow = TRUE, ncol = 10)
all_vals <- numeric(ncol(mat))
for (i in seq(ncol(mat))) {
   all_vals[i] <- sum(mat[, i])
}

all_vals
#[1] 105 110 115 120 125 130 135 140 145 150
```

which gives same value as

```
colSums(mat)
#[1] 105 110 115 120 125 130 135 140 145 150
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I tweaked in a little to correspond with my problem but it worked great!!! You're awesome!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sue, you can try this simple loop, hope it helps address your issue.

```
sum <- 0
for(i in 1:ncol(my_matrix)){
  sum[i] <- sum(my_matrix[,i])
}
```